String contains non ISO-8859-1 code point
When I'm trying run my electronjs app and use window.loadURL('https://example.test'), I catch the following error  from PrecacheCacheKeyPlugin.
Uncaught (in promise)
TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': Failed to read the
'headers' property from 'RequestInit': String contains non
 ISO-8859-1 code point.
    at K.cacheKeyWillBeUsed (PrecacheCacheKeyPlugin.js:24:19)
    at a (StrategyHandler.js:422:40)
    at H.getCacheKey (StrategyHandler.js:355:52)
    at H.cacheMatch (StrategyHandler.js:225:45)
    at $._handle (PrecacheStrategy.js:64:40)
    at $._getResponse (Strategy.js:144:35)

After reload the page (command + R) it works well. When I'm opening my app to browser, it works well too.
I try debug headers screen, it looks good:


Welcome to StackOverflow! Whenever possible, please use code formatting blocks instead of uploading images of code/errors..
